# Test function return different case scenario - Jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Trying to run a test and my function is not returning what I expect based on my case. Not sure if I am applying the conditions correctly

here is the function :

```
renderColumnDropdown = () => {
  if (this.props.columnIdList != undefined) {
  let columnOptions = Object.keys(this.props.columnIdList).map(key => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'sort':
      return false
    case 'filters':
      return false
    })
   return (
    default:
    return (
      <option value={key} key={key}>{this.props.columnIdList[key]}</option>
    )
  return (
   <select value={this.state.column} name='column' id='filter-column' onChange={this.handleChange} defaultValue={this.props.defaultData != null ? this.props.defaultData.column : 'default'}>
    {columnOptions}
  </select>
)
```

Here is what I have for my test so far: using jest and enzyme for React JS

```
it('Test renderColumnDropdown method',() => {
    wrapper.setProps({
        columnIdList:[],
        columnOptions:[{
            case:'sort'
         }]   
     })
     wrapper.update();
     expect(wrapper.instance().renderColumnDropdown({columnOptions:[{case:""}]})).toEqual();
});
```

I expected to return a message saying that is Equal to false, but right now is returning "

What can adjust on my props to make sure I can test each case scenario

Answer (score 2):

`renderColumnDropdown` iterates over `columnIdList` prop, not `columnOptions`.

It likely should be:

```
wrapper.setProps({
    columnIdList:[{
        case:'sort'
     }]   
 })
```

It also doesn't accept arguments like `renderColumnDropdown({columnOptions:[{case:""}]})`

The function returns React elements, they can be rendered:

```
const columnsWrapper = shallow(wrapper.instance().renderColumnDropdown());
```

Then a wrapper can be asserted that options are expected there or not:

```
expect(columnsWrapper.find('select').dive().find('option')).to.have.lengthOf(0);
```

Comment: I made the adjustment already, how could I call it . I tried the following     expect(wrapper.instance().renderColumnDropdown({columnIdList:[{case:""}]})).toEqual(); But sill returning something else

Comment: It's impossible to answer the question precisely without knowing what the code really looks like. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What exactly does it return and what you expect it to return? You're not providing a value for `toEqual`.

Comment: I added the whole function there. I expect the case scenario in this case:'sort' to equal False

Comment: I get the following :    <select defaultValue="" id="filter-column" name="column" onChange={[Function anonymous]} value={undefined}><option value="0">{"case": "sort"}</option><option disabled={true} value="default">Column</option></select>